# Django - confused about naming class and parameters (when to use uppercase / plural form)?

Tags: python, django, class, naming-conventions

Such confusion reflects unclear understanding about class and framework.

I'm learning database in Django models. I get confused about naming class. When to use uppercase / lowercase, when to use singular and plural? I'm following the lecture from [freecodecamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBzwzrDvZ18&t=19742s) with this example:

In `models.py`, I assign a class called `Feature(models.Model)`.

Then, in `views.py`, I assign features for templates:

```
features = def index(request):
Features.objects.all()
return render (request, "index.html", ({"features": features})
```

In `index.html`, there exists a for loop, therefore I run the syntax for feature in features: with the variable `{{feature.name}}` and `{{feature.details}}`

At this moment I just memorize without understanding when deciding when to use Feature vs feature, features vs feature. I find it rather difficult in memorizing the code `views.py`. I need a real understanding about naming.

Below is the flow of some of the code. Thank you so much for your help.

```
models.py
class Feature(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
details = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
------
settings.py
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
----
admin.py
from .models import Feature
admin.site.register(Feature)
----
views.py
def index(req):
features = Feature.objects.all()
return render(req, "index.html", ({'features': features})
----
index.html
for feature in features:
....{feature.name}
....{feature.details}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes in Python are, by convention, specified in *PascalCase*, so these start with an uppercase. Models usually have a *singular* name, so `Feature`, not <s>`Features`</s>: this is because a *single* `Feature` objects works with *one* such `Feature`, not a *collection* of `Feature`s.

Variables on the other hand are written in *snake_case*, so `feature` or `features` and `author_of_book` instead of <s>`authorOfBook`</s>. If we make a query like:

```
Feature.objects.all()
```

the result is a `QuerySet` of `Feature` objects, so a *collection*. While the collection can have zero, one, or more elements. If we work with a collection of things, we use plural, even if that collection has only a single element, or no elements at all. So it makes sense to name this `features`: it hints that we are dealing with a collection of things. We do the same for lists, sets, tuples, etc. of items.

Finally if we *enumerate* over `features`, then we will thus enumerate over each item, these items will be a single `Feature` item, hence it makes sense that this name is singular, so `feature`, not `features`.

Comment: Thank you Willem. You provide me a guide. I will follow this in designing names.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the accepted answer, all python naming conventions are defined in PEP8, which you can read here:

https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions